# Validation and Test accuracy at random performance, whereas Train accuracy very high

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, resnet, batch-normalization

I am trying to build a classifier in TensorFlow2.1 for *CIFAR10* using *ResNet50* pre-trained over *imagenet* from *keras.application* and then stacking a small FNN on top of it:

```
# Load ResNet50 pre-trained on imagenet
resn = applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), pooling='avg', include_top=False)
```

```
# Load CIFAR10 
(c10_train, c10_test), info = tfds.load(name='cifar10', split=['train', 'test'], with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

# Make sure all the layers are not trainable
for layer in resn.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Transfert Learning for CIFAR10: fine-tune the network by stacking a trainable FNN on top of Resnet
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers

def build_model():
  model = models.Sequential()
  # Feature extractor
  model.add(resn)
  # Small FNN
  model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
  model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model

# Build the resulting net
resn50_c10 = build_model()
```

I am facing the following issue when it comes to validate or test the accuracy:

```
history = resn50_c10.fit_generator(c10_train.shuffle(1000).batch(BATCH_SIZE), validation_data=c10_test.batch(BATCH_SIZE), epochs=20)

Epoch 1/20
25/25 [==============================] - 113s 5s/step - loss: 0.9659 - accuracy: 0.6634 - val_loss: 2.8157 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 2/20
25/25 [==============================] - 109s 4s/step - loss: 0.8908 - accuracy: 0.6920 - val_loss: 2.8165 - val_accuracy: 0.1094
Epoch 3/20
25/25 [==============================] - 116s 5s/step - loss: 0.8743 - accuracy: 0.7038 - val_loss: 2.7555 - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 4/20
25/25 [==============================] - 132s 5s/step - loss: 0.8319 - accuracy: 0.7166 - val_loss: 2.8398 - val_accuracy: 0.1013
Epoch 5/20
25/25 [==============================] - 132s 5s/step - loss: 0.7903 - accuracy: 0.7253 - val_loss: 2.8624 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 6/20
25/25 [==============================] - 132s 5s/step - loss: 0.7697 - accuracy: 0.7325 - val_loss: 2.8409 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 7/20
25/25 [==============================] - 132s 5s/step - loss: 0.7515 - accuracy: 0.7406 - val_loss: 2.7697 - val_accuracy: 0.1000   
#... (same for the remaining epochs)
```

Although the model seems to learn adequately from the training split, **both the accuracy and loss for the validation set does not improve at all.** What is causing this behavior?

I am excluding this is overfitting since I am applying Dropout and since the model seems to never really improve on the test set.

What I have done so far:

- Check the one-hot labelling is consistent throughout train and test
- Tried different FNN configurations
- Tried the method `fit_generator` instead of `fit`
- Preprocess the image, resized the images w/ different input_shapes

and experienced always the same problem.

Any hint would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Drop the dropout (it should never be used by default, only if suspecting overfitting), and lower your learning rate (try 0.01).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've already tried different learning rates, up to 0.01 (did not go lower tho). Following your advice I removed dropout but still nothing changed. It seems to me it must be a problem related either with data or a code bug. It looks like the weights are reset to random when validating for each epoch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was caused uniquely by the use of `ResNet50`.

As a workaround, I downloaded and used other pre-trained deep networks such as `keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16`, `keras.applications.densenet.DenseNet121` and the accuracy on the test set increased as expected.

**UPDATE**

The above part of this answer is just a palliative. In order to understand what is really happening and eventually use transfer learning properly with ResNet50, keep on reading.

The root cause appears to be found in how `Keras` handles the `Batch Normalization` layer:

> During fine-tuning, if a Batch Normalization layer is frozen it uses the mini-batch statistics. I believe this is incorrect and it can lead to reduced accuracy especially when we use Transfer learning. A better approach in this case would be to use the values of the moving mean and variance.

As explained more in-depth here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9965

Even though the correct approach has been implemented in *TensorFlow 2* when we use `tf.keras.applications` we reference the *TensorFlow 1.0* behavior for Batch Normalization. That's why we need to explicitly inject the reference to *TensorFlow 2* by adding the argument `layers=tf.keras.layers` when loading modules. So in my case, the loading of ResNet50 will become

```
history = resn50_c10.fit_generator(c10_train.shuffle(1000).batch(BATCH_SIZE), validation_data=c10_test.batch(BATCH_SIZE), epochs=20, layers=tf.keras.layers)
```

and that will do the trick.

Credits for the solution to @rpeloff: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9965#issuecomment-549126009

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to loading data using `tfds` and then passing to Keras `.fit`

Try to load your data with

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

And then

```
fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=20, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.2, validation_data=None, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, even with this workaround the problem persists. The behavior I am experiencing seem to suggest that when tensorflow calls the `.evaluate` method, the learned weights are set back to random forgetting the learned ones. I am fairly new to TensorFlow so I might be missing something trivial but I really cant understand what.